# How to find if same items has different price in the csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have CSV file which is having 2 columns like items ,price here the same items are presents multiple time in the column means It should have a same price ,if that is differ the script should gives the warning message ..

```
with open(filepath, "r") as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
for lines in csv_reader:
    print(lines['mpn']+"\t -"+ lines['value'])
```

Comment: Please provide a small test CSV and the code you've written so far. We generally don't do all of the work for you.

Comment: @tdelaney well i added the code what i tried i just try to print the values after that i didn't get the logic what to do if you know please help

Answer (score 0):

You can accumulate prices for a given item in a dictionary and then look for price differences once you've filled it in. `collections.defaultdict` is a helper that removes some of the bookkeeping for updating the dict (it auto-creates keys when a new key is seen) and `set` is a useful way to check for differences in the values.

This code adds prices to a set of prices for each item.

```
import collections

with open(filepath, "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    items = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for item, price in csv_reader:
        items[item].add(price)
for item, price_set in items.items():
    if len(price_set) > 1:
        print(f"Warning: {item} has multiple prices {price_set}")
```

Comment: it gives this error NameError: name 'defaultdict' is not defined

Comment: @sundhar - fixed

Comment: for mpn, value in csv_reader:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: instead of item, price i'm using mpn,value dont confuse with that FYI